# How to repeat in AngularJS with ng-repeat from a specific index value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I wish to list the first 5 elements of some array I'd likely do this

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in some_array | limitTo:5">{{item.name}}</li></ul>
```

Very well. Suppose I then want to list the rest after putting a specific HTML snippet in between... e.g.

```
<h3>Some HTML block code</h3>
```

How do I then resume the iteration conveniently with something like this (or similar easier)?

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in some_array | startFrom:6">{{item.name}}</li></ul>
```

The real code is not quite as trivial... for instance the first iteration uses `<li></li>` and includes images, while the last iteration uses only `<a href=""></a>`... The point remains how to resume an iteration or start it from a specific index number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in newTestArr | limitTo:5 track by $index">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>

<h3> ng-repeat="item in newTestArr track by $index" ng-show="$index > 5">{{item.name}}</h3>
```

Comment: this would work, but you probably should use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` here, and you would also need to take special care if other filters are applied as well, since they can affect `$index`.

Comment: it depend which interaction you want to use later if you want apply some events with ng-if you cant beacuse DOM it does not exists

Comment: That is true, but the elements do in fact exist on the page already, in a different repeated group.